# How to get click on board in an activity class in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view, onclick

I am wondering how to create a listener that would react when I click on the boardView (that extends View) which is set to ContentView in the Activity class. The code is below.

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private LiftGame game;
private LiftPlayer playerRed;
private LiftPlayer playerBlack;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BoardView boardView = new BoardView(this);
    setContentView(boardView);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("CONFIG", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    createGame();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `boardView.setOnClickListener`?